# Starting new activity triggered by boolean in GameThread (android)

Tags: android, android-activity, surfaceview

I am making a "Defend the castle" style android application. The game is complete, however I just need help closing my surfaceview and starting a new activity for when the the player has lost the game.

The condition for losing the game is just a boolean variable in my GameThread class. The variable is called "lost" and is by default set to false. When the life of the castle drops below 1, lost is set to true and a sound effect plays.

Ideally, I would like to stop the currently looping sound effects and open a new activity (which is already made and working) upon lost=true.

The main activity is as follows:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button btn_startGame;
    Activity activity;

    GameView mGameView;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        activity = this;

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        btn_startGame = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStartGame);
        btn_startGame.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            //@Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mGameView = new GameView(activity);
                setContentView(mGameView);
                mGameView.mThread.doStart();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        try {
            mGameView.mThread.onTouch(event);
        } catch(Exception e) {}

        return true;
    }

    @Override 
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) { 
      // ignore orientation/keyboard change 
      super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig); 
    } 
}
```

The surfaceview is created in this class called GameView:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder.Callback;

public class GameView extends SurfaceView implements Callback {

    Context mContext;
    GameThread mThread;

    public GameView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.mContext = context;

        getHolder().addCallback(this);

        mThread = new GameThread(getHolder(), mContext, new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message m) {
                // Use for pushing back messages.
            }
        });

        setFocusable(true);
    }

    //@Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {

        Log.d(this.getClass().toString(), "in SurfaceChanged()");
    }

    //@Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        Log.d(this.getClass().toString(), "in SurfaceCreated()");
        mThread.running = true;
        mThread.start();
    }

    //@Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        Log.d(this.getClass().toString(), "in SurfaceDestroyed()");

        boolean retry = true;
        mThread.running = false;
        while (retry) {
            try {
                mThread.join();
                retry = false;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
            GameThread.music.stop();
            GameThread.groan1.stop();
            GameThread.groan2.stop();
            GameThread.walk.stop();

            GameThread.music.release();
            GameThread.groan1.release();
            GameThread.groan2.release();
            GameThread.walk.release();
            GameThread.shoot.release();
        }
    }

}
```

The GameThread class contains all of the drawing, the logic and all a run method (below).

```
@Override
    public void run() {
         // check if condition here 
         if(lost){
            mContext.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //start Activity here

                  Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, LoseActivity.class);
                  mContext.startActivity(intent);
             }
             }); 
            }
           else{
        if (running == true) {
            while (running) {
                Canvas c = null;
                try {
                    c = mHolder.lockCanvas();
                    if (width == 0) {
                        width = c.getWidth();
                        height = c.getHeight();

                        player.x = 50;
                        player.y = 45;
                    }

                    synchronized (mHolder) {
                        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();

                        update();
                        draw(c);
                        ifps++;

                        if (now > (mLastTime + 1000)) {
                            mLastTime = now;
                            fps = ifps;
                            ifps = 0;
                        }
                    }
                } finally {
                    if (c != null) {
                        mHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
       }
```

The activity that I want to start is called LoseActivity.class. Thank you in advance for any and all help. If anybody needs any further code/explanations, I will be more than happy to post it.

Answer (score 1):

Use [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) for starting Activity from Thread as:

Change your main Activity as:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button btn_startGame;
    Activity activity;

    GameView mGameView;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        activity = this;

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        btn_startGame = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStartGame);
        btn_startGame.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            //@Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mGameView = new GameView(activity,MainActivity.this);
                setContentView(mGameView);
                mGameView.mThread.doStart();
            }
        });
    }
  ///your code.....
```

Change your GameView class as:

```
public class GameView extends SurfaceView implements Callback {

    Context mContext;
    Activity contextx;
    GameThread mThread;

    public GameView(Context context,Activity contextx) {
        super(context);
        this.mContext = context;
        this.contextx=contextx;

        getHolder().addCallback(this);

        mThread = new GameThread(getHolder(), mContext, new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message m) {
                // Use for pushing back messages.
            }
        });

        setFocusable(true);
    }
  //your code here..........

@Override
    public void run() {
         // check if condition here 
         if(lost){
            contextx.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //start Activity here

                  Intent intent = new Intent(contextx, LoseActivity.class);
                  contextx.startActivity(intent);
             }
             }); 
            }
           else{
  //your code here.........
```

Comment: When i paste your code into my GameView constructor, I get an error that says, "The method runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){}) is undefined for the type Context". What does that mean, and how can I fix it? Also, assuming this were working, would I just place an if statement above the intent checking if lost=true?

Comment: don't place my code in GameView constructor. just copy past it where u want to start activity in Thread within run method of Thread and place your if condition within run method of runOnUiThread . i think this will work f9

Comment: Ok, so I put it in the run method of GameThread and it says that runOnUiThread is undefined for type Context. What have I done wrong?

Comment: @L337Man : can u plz edit your post with latest code what u have tried including my code and also use `activty=MainActivity.this` in MainActivity class

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I have edited my code above. I put your code in the run() method within my GameThread class.

Comment: have you tried it by passing mGameView = new GameView(MainActivity.this);?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. I'm sorry. I don't think I have.

Comment: change  //@Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               ` mGameView = new GameView(MainActivity.this);
                setContentView(mGameView);
                mGameView.mThread.doStart();
            }` in MainActivity Activity

Comment: After making that change, I'm still getting an error in GameThread that reads: "mContext" cannot be resolved. I have a variable named ctx which is set to the context parameter from the GameThread constructor, but when I switch mContext to ctx, it says: "The method runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){}) is undefined for the type Context"

Comment: I am still getting the same error. When I mouse over contextx.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() I get "The method runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){}) is undefined for the type Context"

Comment: Thank you for your help so far. Unfortunately, although there are no more errors, it just isn't working. When the game is lost, the sound effect plays however the activity doesn't start.

Comment: if it's running f9 using runOnUiThread then put log inside runOnUiThread run method and check control is going inside runOnUiThread or not

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20586/discussion-between-imran-khan-and-l337man)